# datatable server-side href variable

Tags: php, ajax, json, datatables, server-side

I am using the example for server side datatables plugin http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

It works fine, but now I'm trying to change the code for my table, because the example is not exactly how I want my table to look like.

There is one problem :

```
{
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "setid" )
        {
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]) ? '<a href=\'http://osu.ppy.sh/d/$aRow[ $aColumns[$i]]\'>test</a>'  : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}
```

The problem is right here :

```
$row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]) ? '<a href=\'http://osu.ppy.sh/d/$aRow[ $aColumns[$i]]\'>test</a>'  : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
```

When I click "test" in my table it goes to http://osu.py.sh/d/$aRow[$aColumns[$i] ]] instead of the ID.

As far as I know the ID I need is in $aRow[ $aColumns[$i]]; 
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [double quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) for variable names to be be expanded inside a string.

However, as you are using 3 variables, I would concatenate the string instead to avoid confusion:

```
$row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]
           ? ('<a href=\'http://osu.ppy.sh/d/' . $aRow[$aColumns[$i]] . '\'>test</a>')
           : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I had to put the ( ) away tho.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line

```
$row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]) ? '<a href=\'http://osu.ppy.sh/d/$aRow[ $aColumns[$i]]\'>test</a>'  : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
```

to

```
$row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]) ? '<a href=\'http://osu.ppy.sh/d/'.$aRow[ $aColumns[$i]].'\'>test</a>'  : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
```